# Jenkins declarative pipeline set global environment var from output of previous stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

in Jenkins declarative pipeline, is there a way to set a global environment var of a stage based on the output of the previous stage? I would like to be able to dynamically set an agent based on this. I have a code that does not work (below), but this illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
pipeline {
  agent { node { label 'standard' } }

  stages {
    stage ('first') {
      steps {
        sh 'MYSTRING=`myapp.py getstring`'
      }
    }
    stage ('second') {
      agent { node { label "${MYSTRING}-agent" } }
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting an ephemeral shell variable to the value of a stdout. You need to set a Jenkins variable to the value of a stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work.

```
class Global{
    static nextNode
}

pipeline {
  agent { label 'standard' } 
  stages {
    stage ('first') {
      steps {
          script {
            Global.nextNode=sh(script: 'myapp.py getstring', returnStdout: true).trim()
          }
      }
    }
    stage ('second') {
      agent { label "${Global.nextNode}-agent" } 
    }
  }
}
```

But I would strongly recommend that you forget about the declarative pipeline syntax as it will probably cause you to grow gray hairs very quickly!

Below is an example in scripted mode.
The below example actually works while the above one requires two executors. In my case the master node only has one and so it doesn't work as the agents are nested.

```
node('linux') {
  stage ('first') {
    nextNode=sh(script: 'echo \$NODE_NAME', returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo nextNode
  }
}

node ("${nextNode}") {
  stage ('second') {
    echo nextNode
    sh 'ls'
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! Can you elaborate a little bit why I should forget about declarative pipelines?

Comment: sorry, I spoke to soon. The pipeline is hung on 'second' stage waiting on 'null-agent'. It seems like the variable is able to resolve on the same stage (first) where it was set, but not on the succeeding stages (second)

Comment: Correct, if you have just one executor and the second stage runs on the same node as the first one the declarative example will hang

Comment: As in why to use scripted, well it just works. The declarative has many many issues that you will have to encounter when you move past the simple hello world examples. Save yourself some time and use to scripted.